# Jackson deserialize "simple type" to enum

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a common class

```
public CommonClass {
    private Enum<?> field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private Map<? extends Enum<?>, Map<String, Object>> map;
    // constructor, getters setters
}
```

And two enums

```
public enum A {
  FIELD,
  VALUE
}
public enum B {
   ENUM1,
   ENUM1
}
```

And json to parse in it class

```
{
  "field1": "FIELD",
  "field2": "field2",
  "field3": "field2",
  "map": {
    "ENUM1": {
           // some inner data
      },
    "ENUM2":{
          // some inner data
    }
   }
}
```

When I try to parse this JSON to an object I got an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constants for class java.lang.Enum
```

This exception occurs when Jackson tried to deserialize "ENUM1" which is a **? extends Enum<?>** to **B**
When I debug it, Jackson thought that this property is **simple type**.
Is any suggestion why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot deserialize even this simplified one by default:

```
public class CommonClass {
    private Enum<?> field1;     
}
```

I is because no `Enum` nor `enum` has public no args constructor. To serialize beforementioned is easy. But to deserialize you need to know **which** enum and which value. So if you had:

```
public class CommonClass {
    private A field1;       
}
```

It would work because Jackson sees the enum is of type `A` and - I guess - makes it like:

```
A.valueOf("FIELD");
```

And as you see here `A` is static. `Enum`s are static and also their values are final.

If you want to deserialize arbitrary generic enum value `Enum<?>` you need to have custom deserializer that determines the enum type and together with value and gets instance of enum like above. And you might also need a custom serializer that serializes also the type for custom deserializer to read.

Comment: Jackson deserialized Enum<?> field1 without any problem. It cannot deserialize key in map Map<? extends Enum<?>, Map<String, Object>> map

Comment: @TarasDanylchenko So did you try my simplified class? It does not work for me.